# Make always rebuilding

Tags: makefile

## Problem

I am trying to refactor my Makefile to reflect the insights given in [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf). The difference between my use case and the one described in the paper is that it considers acceptable to have the object and dependency files in the same directory as the source and headers, which for my case is undesirable.

## Dependency file generation

The `depend.sh` script is copied from the paper. It generates a dependency file with data from gcc according to a layout of subdirectories. Unless i typed it wrong I do not think the error lies here:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$1"
shift 1
case "$DIR" in
"" | ".")
g++ -std=c++0x  -MM -MG "$@"  | sed -e 's@^\(.*\)\.o:@\1.d \1.o:@'
;;
*)
g++ -std=c++0x  -MM -MG "$@" | sed -e "s@^\(.*\)\.o:@$DIR/\1.d $DIR/\1.o:@"
;;
esac
```

My code tree resembles the one below:
[image]

## Question

I have made adaptations and the make file looks like this. What am I doing wrong, that when I run `make new_make` it always recompiles even though the dependency files are correct?

Also, I am correct that if the dependency file has a requirement for the header file, then any change to it would cause a recompilation of it?

## Makefile example

```
PROJECT_DIRECTORY:=$(shell git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
MAKEFILE_DIRECTORY:=$(PROJECT_DIRECTORY)/Software
CONTRIB_DIRECTORY:=$(MAKEFILE_DIRECTORY)/contrib
SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY:=$(CONTRIB_DIRECTORY)/scripts
OBJECTS_DIRECTORY:=$(MAKEFILE_DIRECTORY)/obj


INC:=$(CONTRIB_DIRECTORY)

INC_PARAMS:=$(foreach d, $(INC), -I$d)
LD_PARAMS:=$(foreach d, $(LIB_NAMES), -l$d) -lpthread
LDFLAGS:=-L./$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)

CC:=g++
CPPFLAGS:=-c $(INC_PARAMS)
CXXFLAGS:=-std=c++0x $(OTHER_D_FLAGS)

MODULES:=src
ACFLAGS= $(patsubst %,-I%,$(MODULES))   
MODULES_OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %,$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/%,$(MODULES))


SRC:=
include $(patsubst %,%/module.mk,$(MODULES))

check_dirs:
    check_dir.sh

OBJ:=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/%.o, $(filter %.cpp,$(SRC)))

new_make: $(OBJ)
    $(CC)  -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LD_PARAMS)

$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/%.o: $(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/%.d
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(ACFLAGS) $(INC_PARAMS) $*.cpp -o $@

$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/%.d: %.cpp
    contrib/scripts/depend.sh $(dirname $*.cpp) $(MODULES) $*.cpp > $@

-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)

.PHONY: clean new_make check_dirs
```

## Example dependency file for src/MavCommunication.d

```
src/MavCommunication.d src/MavCommunication.o: src/MavCommunication.cpp src/MavCommunication.h \
src/SerialCommunication.h src/ICommunication.h src/Hardware.h \
src/IColor.h mavlink/common/mavlink.h src/ActionRequestState.h \
src/Waypoint.h mavlink/ardupilotmega/mavlink.h \
mavlink/ardupilotmega/ardupilotmega.h
```

## make -d output for src/MavCommunication.d part

Here I think that the .h requisite of .d is not honored by make

```
Considering target file `/media/truecrypt1/Projects/master_thesis.master/Software/obj/src/MavCommunication.d'.
Looking for an implicit rule for `/media/truecrypt1/Projects/master_thesis.master/Software/obj/src/MavCommunication.d'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `src/MavCommunication'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `src/MavCommunication.cpp'.
Found an implicit rule for `/media/truecrypt1/Projects/master_thesis.master/Software/obj/src/MavCommunication.d'.
Considering target file `src/MavCommunication.cpp'.
Looking for an implicit rule for `src/MavCommunication.cpp'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `MavCommunication.cpp'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `src/MavCommunication.cpp,v'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `MavCommunication.cpp'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `src/RCS/MavCommunication.cpp,v'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `MavCommunication.cpp'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `src/RCS/MavCommunication.cpp'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `MavCommunication.cpp'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `src/s.MavCommunication.cpp'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `MavCommunication.cpp'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `src/SCCS/s.MavCommunication.cpp'.
No implicit rule found for `src/MavCommunication.cpp'.
Finished prerequisites of target file `src/MavCommunication.cpp'.
No need to remake target `src/MavCommunication.cpp'.
Finished prerequisites of target file `/media/truecrypt1/Projects/master_thesis.master/Software/obj/src/MavCommunication.d'.
Prerequisite `src/MavCommunication.cpp' is older than target `/media/truecrypt1/Projects/master_thesis.master/Software/obj/src/MavCommunication.d'.
```

Comment: Why not migrate to a build system like SCONS or Gradle?

Comment: `check_dirs` is a `.PHONY` target. They cannot be prerequisites of real targets. See the quote in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27425276/258523) from the GNU Make manual. Also run `make -d` and see what it says it is doing and why.

Comment: Also, you seem to to be telling make to load `.d` files from next to the object files but telling make to *create* the `.d` files next to the `.cpp` files, no? `$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.d`, `%.d: %.cpp` and `-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)`

Comment: @Etan Reisner: can you write that up as the answer?

Comment: @Etan Reisner: The problem with the .phoney target was not the main one, although I already corrected it. On the other hand the problem with the wrong generation .d files was semi-right. Upon correcting them, no more rebuilding happened but if I change the .h files no recompilation happens as it should.

Comment: Update the question with your corrected makefile and the output from `make -d` when it fails to rebuild as well as the contents of the `.d` files in question.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: Hope it is more complete now. Making a change in MavCommunication.h still doesn't cause a recompile.

Comment: `/media/truecrypt1/Projects/master_thesis.master/Software/obj/src/MavCommunication.d` does not appear to be the correct path. You aren't stripping `src/` from the `.cpp` file paths before creating the `.d` files. Also notice the contents of the `.d` file. The target is `src/MavCommunication.d src/MavCommunication.o:` neither of which file exists or is being built.

Comment: Also the incorrect `.d` file stuff was likely not the constant rebuilding problem but is certainly the not rebuilding problem. I would probably suggest that you mark my answer as correct and file a new question about the not-rebuilding question since they are different things.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: I figured it out with your help. I say, I revert the makefile shown in the question to the first version so that it reflects the rebuild problem. You edit your question to have the `$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.d, %.d: %.cpp and -include $(OBJ:.o=.d)` problem pointed out as that was the real cause for the question's problem. Then I will create another question about the header problems and you will answer it with the fact that the contents of the .d file were not correct. Is that ok for you?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_dirs` is a `.PHONY` target.

`.PHONY` targets cannot (well should not) be prerequisites of real targets as section [4.6 Phony Targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) in the manual says:

> A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time make goes to update that file. As long as a phony target is never a prerequisite of a real target, the phony target recipe will be executed only when the phony target is a specified goal (see Arguments to Specify the Goals).

Additionally the output from running `make -d` will tell you what make is doing and why it is doing so.

Additionally additionally, the paths used for the `.d` files in that makefile are not consistent.

You are telling make to load the files (`-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)`) from next to the `.o` files but you are telling make to create the `.d` files next to the `.c` files `$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.d` and `%.d: %.cpp`. This is almost certainly causing make to simply fail to find the `.d` files to include.